# How to autoresize a wysihtml5 textarea correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, autoresize, wysihtml5, bootstrap-wysihtml5

I am using [bootstrap-wysihtml5](https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5) so receive input from a textarea input field. To improve the user experience I want to autoresize the textarea to fit the input text.

With help from the code in [this Gist](https://gist.github.com/ifightcrime/5633086) I am able to resize the textarea when clicked, but not on load.

Here is my current implementation:

```
var container = $("#container");
var textarea = $("<textarea />");
textarea.attr("style", "width: 90%;");

container.append(textarea);

textarea.wysihtml5({
  "font-styles": false,
  "emphasis": false,
  "lists": false,
  "html": false,
  "link": false,
  "image": false,
  "color": false
});

textarea.val("<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</div<div><br></div><div>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur..</div");

textarea.observe("load", function () {     
  var $iframe = $(this.composer.iframe);
  var $body = $(this.composer.element);    // <body marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" contenteditable="true" class="wysihtml5-editor" spellcheck="true" style="color: rgb(85, 85, 85); cursor: auto; font-family: HelveticaNeue-Light, 'Helvetica Neue Light', 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, 'Lucida Grande', sans-serif; font-size: 14px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; line-height: 20px; letter-spacing: normal; text-align: start; text-decoration: none; text-indent: 0px; text-rendering: auto; word-break: normal; word-wrap: break-word; word-spacing: 0px; min-height: 0px; overflow: hidden; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);"><div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.<br></div><div>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur..</div></body>

  $body.css({
    'min-height': 0,
    'line-height': '20px',
    'overflow': 'hidden',
  })

  var scrollHeightInit = $body[0].scrollHeight;                // 3860
  var bodyHeightInit = $body.height();                         // 3860
  var heightInit = Math.min(scrollHeightInit, bodyHeightInit); // 3860
  $iframe.height(heightInit);

  $body.bind('keypress keyup keydown paste change focus blur', function(e) {
    var scrollHeight = $body[0].scrollHeight;        // 150
    var bodyHeight = $body.height();                 // 60
    var height = Math.min(scrollHeight, bodyHeight); // 60
    $iframe.height(height);
  });
});
```

As you can see `height` is evaluated to *60*, which is correct. But `heightInit` is evaluated to *3860*, which is not correct. How do I fix this?

Comment: can you post a minimal working example of your code ?

Comment: Hi @GabyakaG.Petrioli. The above code does work. It just give me a wrong  `heightInit` value. So if you want to test it you should be able to do so and then confirm my findings by doing `console.log(heightInit);`.

Comment: I meant if there is a live page (*http://jsfiddle.net, http://codepen.io*) so we do not have to create a full page with all plugins etc..

Comment: I wish I could. I've tried for the last few hours to create a jfiddle, but I don't have the skills to set it up without getting all sorts of errors that I'm not getting on me own app.

Comment: Hello,

I guess your problem is fitting `wysihtml5` according to document `height`. Isn't it?
I've worked with `wysihtml5` in my project. Note this functions. These may be solve your issue. `$(document).height()` and `$(window).height()`   Actually I couldn't fully understand your problem.

Comment: Hi @user3765109. I don't want to fir my wysihtml5 form to document height. I want to fit it to the text inside. But apparently I can't get the correct height of the text before I manually click on the textarea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`bootstrap-wysihtml5` has an `events` property; one of these events is the `load` event.

> To resize the textarea on load, all you need to do is **declare a `load` event within the `textarea.wysihtml5` configuration function**;

See code below:

**Code**

```
textarea.wysihtml5({
  ...other properties....,
  "events": {
    "load": function() {
      console.log("Loaded!");
      var $iframe = $(this.composer.iframe);
      var $body = $(this.composer.element);
      $body.css({
        'min-height': 0,
        'line-height': '20px',
        'overflow': 'hidden',
      });
      var scrollHeightInit = $body[0].scrollHeight;
      console.log("scrollHeightInit", scrollHeightInit);
      var bodyHeightInit = $body.height();
      console.log("bodyHeightInit", bodyHeightInit);
      var heightInit = Math.min(scrollHeightInit, bodyHeightInit);
      $iframe.height(heightInit);
    }
  }
});
```

Here is [**Working Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/FbwxJMb2uZsH5crQdEW2?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Manube's answer doesn't work for me. I don't know why. I got the console log from `$body` and `$iframe`. But failed to set `$body.css` and `$iframe.height()`. I adopted `document.getElementsByClassName('wysihtml5-sandbox')[0].setAttribute()` instead. Then it worked. The change event's UX to auto resize iframe is not good though.
Manube's answer helped me a lot and it is very simple. Thank you!
Here is the code I used:

```
$('#edit').wysihtml5({
    toolbar:{ "fa": true, "image": false, "html": false },
    locale: 'zh-TW',
    name: 't-iframe',
    events: {
        load: function(){
            var $body = $(this.composer.element);
            var $iframe = $(this.composer.iframe);
            iframeh = Math.max($body[0].scrollHeight, $body.height()) + 100;
            document.getElementsByClassName('wysihtml5-sandbox')[0].setAttribute('style','height: ' + iframeh +'px !important');
},change: function(){
            var $abody = $(this.composer.element);
            var $aiframe = $(this.composer.iframe);
            aiframeh = Math.max($abody[0].scrollHeight, $abody.height()) + 100;
            document.getElementsByClassName('wysihtml5-sandbox')[0].setAttribute('style','height: ' + aiframeh +'px !important');
        }
    }
});
```